# Instagram: Unable to retrieve media

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I've created an application in sandbox on Instagram and I just noticed that despite having the users be a part of my sandbox environment and also following them (and being followed) on Instagram, I am UNABLE to retrieve the media of ONLY those users who've set their account as Private Account. I am able to retrieve media of all the users who've not set any privacy on their account regardless of whether they follow me/I follow them or not.

Now, despite me following and being followed by some users, and also including them as sandbox users of my app, why am I unable to retrieve their data?

```
API Used: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Link: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram API no longer allows retrieving private profiles even if the user has been approved by the private user. This change went into effect with the June 1st 2016 API changes.

private profile can be retrieved using API using the private profile's `access_token`, but not any other user's `access_token` (even if approved)